# Why PIL.Image saves black or grayscale image?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I am working on a BMP file.
I need to save a resized, smaller version of this file. But the PIL. Image does save grayscale image. I want to save colorful image.
How can I solve it?
This is a part of my code

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import ImageFile

ibmp = Image.open('E:/Project files/label1.bmp') 
width, height = ibmp.size
imgNEW = ibmp.resize((round(width/200), round(height/200)))
ImgArray = np.asarray(imgNEW)           #Array of uint8
image=Image.fromarray(ImgArray)
image_rgb=image.convert('RGB')       # Mode:RGB
image_rgb.save("E:/Project files/Outout/image_rgb.png")
#Imagenew=(image*255).astype(np.uint8)
#Imagenew.save("E:/Project files/Outout//Imagenew.tif")
plt.imshow(image_rgb)
```

By using these codes, could not save an image in color. But, if I want to show it, it is in color.
Here you can see the output! It should be in other colors.

[image: output]

Comment: Your code is incomplete, and you don't show your input image nor your expected and actual output image. Are you trying to save a TIFF, or a BMP, or PNG? Please click [edit] and ensure your code is runnable.

Comment: The input file that is a BMP file is really huge! The shape is (130000, 80000) , I can not show it here or also see it on my pc. It should be a colorful image, and I want to see a small version of it with RGB values, but what I got is grayscale!

Comment: I don't understand why you are making a Numpy array?

Comment: @MarkSetchell because the bmp file is too big, is there any other way?

Comment: If you print `ibmp.mode` what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

**small_im is not defined but if you can use  image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)**

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import ImageFile
import cv2
ibmp = Image.open('./1 no.jpeg')
width, height = ibmp.size
imgNEW = ibmp.resize((round(width/200), round(height/200)))
ImgArray = np.asarray(imgNEW)  # Array of uint8
image = Image.fromarray(ImgArray)    
plt.imsave("./image_rgb.png", image,cmap='gray')
plt.imshow(image)
```

Comment: I changed the variable of small_im. thanks

Comment: I need to save non-grayscale image. The problem is it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I must be missing some aspect of your question. Let's start with this 500x500 image:

[image]

Then load it, reduce its size and save:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('image.png').resize((80,80)).save('result.bmp')
```

**Output**

[image]

---

Quick example with `libvips`. Starting with a 20000x20000 image, reduce to 2500x2500:

```
vipsthumbnail input.bmp -s 2500 -o small.jpg --vips-leak
memory: high-water mark 212.85 MB
```

So that only needed 212MB of RAM.

Comment: So why do you show code that loads it with `Image.open()` and not mention that it fails to open?

Comment: Thank you so much. It works for resized image! If we work on resized image, can be sure that it works on real image? Actually my image size is 4GB and loading on it and working is exposed with some barriers (no enough memory and GPU!).

Comment: Please no mention that comment :) it was a mistack! I meant see it and load it directly as an image.

Comment: Maybe you are on Windows and it's 32-bit and limited to 4GB. If you are really stuck and have such large images, consider looking at `libvips` - it is VERY frugal with memory.

Comment: It is windows and 64-bit. I have 300 huge images and working on this image is just a pilot! I'll try this libvips.

Comment: You can type `[vips]` into StackOverflow Search-box to find questions tagged with `vips`. `libvips` has Python bindings too.

Comment: I added a `vips` example to my answer for you.

Comment: Sadly, libvips uses imagemagick for BMP load and save, so it will be very slow and need loads of memory :( I wouldn't use BMP as an image format myself but I realize we dorks often don't have a choice :( Something like PPM is even easier to write, and you have a chance of cross-platform support.